# How to resolve conflict between multiple versions of jquery?

Tags: jquery

I realize there are already various answers out there to questions about using multiple jquery versions on a page, but I have not been able to figure out how to apply them.

On my page I have two .js files - one for operating a collapsible menu, and the second for a thickbox gallery. The collapsible menu stopped working when I added the gallery. When I tried to use the no conflict solution from the link below, the menu worked but the gallery images would no longer load.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to add things to both the .html file and the .js files?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../01 Main/includes/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../01 Main/includes/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

jq16min = jQuery.noConflict(true);

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jqlatest): " + jqlatest.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>
```

also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../01 Main/includes/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../01 Main/includes/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_6_min = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_latest = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Comment: What versions of jQuery are you using, and can you post your code? Also i havent really seen thickbox used in years. If thats the script witht he dep. on an older version i would switch to something else that can use a more modern version (>=1.8.x).

Comment: It sounds like your using two jQuery plugins and they conflict with each other. jQuery.noConflict is not going to help with that. To see whats happening we'll need some code.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: @prodigitalson, I'm using jquery-1.6.min and jquery-latest, what would you recommend for a more updated version of thickbox?

Answer (score 4):

it doesn't seem smart at all to use multiple versions of jquery but if you must, you could assign one of the versions to another global variable ie 
link to the first versions

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
window._$ = jQuery;
```

then load the next version;

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

it is a possible duplicate to : [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

ins short his answer:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Had to go through the same thing :)

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing this in the html file, but then neither script worked. Do I need to simultaneously rewrite something in the plug-in files?

Comment: There might be some other problem please post your code in your question as an update ..